# jQuery drag and drop, how to save final content to image?

Tags: jquery, image, drag-and-drop, export

I am implementing jQuery draggable logic:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

However, I am unsure on how to save the final div and it's content to an image? My first thought was to send X/Y coordinates to the backend along with the font size/family and construct the image this way (line by line).

Is this the right way to solve this problem or am I missing something?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "save to image"?

Comment: Export the layout to a JPG/PNG/GIF. I would like to take a product like this: http://radykal.de/codecanyon/fancyproductdesigner/ & improve on it one step that it produces an image with the final image/text combination.